# Slack Integration: Is there a way to auto send posts to Slack from professional edition?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, email-alert, workflowoutboundmessage, process

- **Can and How do I send an Outbound Message to Slack?**
- **Or an Email Alert to Slack?**
- **Or Other Options?**

Outbound Message preferred, as I assume this would provide more detailed capability.

**Example Business Process:**
Web-to-Case Case created with Priority 1, needs message sent to higher tier employees. Slack is the alerting tool of choice. Salesforce is the central system.
Do not have Workflow (Have Process Builder)

Comment: Have you seen [Slack and Salesforce Integration](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/05/slack-salesforce-integration.html)? It would be tricky with a Professional Edition org without the use of Apex for the callout.

Comment: Just trying to get it working.

Comment: I was hoping a Slack webhook would be an option with an outbound message. 
But not sure how to fire the outbound message in PE without WF.
Assuming that is a dead end now.

Comment: Salesforce have removed Visualforce Actions from Process Builder from Spring 16

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Slack app on the AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFo7gUAD). It sounds like you can link a Salesforce object to post to Slack.

> The Slack app from the Salesforce AppExchange
>
> - Link Salesforce records with channels in your Slack workspace
> - Share messages between Slack and Chatter

[Source](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/227838227-Salesforce-for-Slack)

That might be a good option for a Professional Edition org.

Otherwise, if you did have Apex there are options in [Slack and Salesforce Integration](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/05/slack-salesforce-integration.html).

Comment: So Cannot use Outbound Messaging in PE?

Comment: @NZDev what would receive the custom Outbound Message SOAP request? Do you have another server that could act as an intermediary and relay the messages over to the Slack web hook?

Comment: Yes I do have that worst case. but want more simple architecture.
I was hoping to format the message according to Slack Webhook:
Send a JSON string within a parameter of a standard POST request
https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks

Comment: @NZDev All very doable with Apex. But in a professional edition org I think you will need to cobble something together from the available parts. The AppExchange package seems like a good way to get some level of integration.

Comment: If you want to go hardcore you could make your own app exchange package that would then run in a Professional Edition org.

Comment: Currently trying to javascript a VF page to submit on render, to Post to Slack Web Hook???
Then put into Action, and fire from Process Builder.
:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this one, but for anyone looking at this now, here is an article about an unmanaged package that allows you to send Slack Messages from a Record-Triggered flow. Additionally it supports mrkdwn in the message so that you can format the message as desired. Not to mention it's completely free.

[Article Link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/send-slack-messages-notifications-via-salesforce-flow-tyler-edwards)